# EasClientDeviceInformation.Id for device identification winrt

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am building an app which requires a user to be uniquely identified on the server without him logging in.

I have already evaluated the App Specific Hardware ID but that seems to be dependent on the hardware config of the machine and if the user even changes a network device, it will change.

Can the EasClientDeviceInformation class along with the Id property be used for this purpose?

Thanks,
Rajeev

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN article on the EasClientDeviceInformation.Id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.exchangeactivesyncprovisioning.easclientdeviceinformation.id.aspx), the Id is a:

> GUID truncated from the first 16 bytes of the SHA256 hash of the MachineID, User SID, and Package Family Name where the MachineID uses the SID of the local users group.

This means that the Id should be unique for each user account and machine combination. However, I imagine a cloned OS will have the same EasClientDeviceInformation.Id. If this is not a concern for your app, then it should be enough to use by itself.

The ASHWID, if you only use the components that shouldn't change, could be another option for you. [MSDN has a detailed article on how to use it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx).
You should definitely ignore the audio, network and Bluetooth components, as I've found they get removed if you do something as trivial as turning on airplane mode, or unplug a headset.